# How can I get around a pywin32 dependency in a python app in docker?

Tags: python, linux, windows, docker, pywin32

I have a python 3.6 application that has to build and import a c# library, and deploy several celery workers via windows services. The application is deployed on azure on windows virtual machines, but I have to figure out how to create a platform independent docker setup that our developers can run locally (some of them have linux machines). At first I tried to find a windows base image for python, but the ones I tried to pull failed and then I found this piece of documentation on the docker hub:

```
Windows requires the host OS version to match the container OS version. If you want to run a container based on a newer Windows build, make sure you have an equivalent host build.
```

- which leads me to believe that there's no point in creating a container with a windows base image because those of us with linux machines won't be able to use it.

The two windows-based dependencies that I have to install are pythonnet pywin32==223. I managed to install pythonnet by first installing mono, but it seems there's no way to install pywin32==223 on my linux container (FROM python:36).

Is there a way to set up a pywin32 and pythonnet compatible base image that can run on both windows and linux hosts, or do we need to rethink our use of windows services and windows hosts in production altogether?

Comment: I think you need to use Windows Docker Container for pywin32 to install. -> https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/468