# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 on cpanel

Tags: python-3.x, django, cpanel, pywin32, pywin

My os is windows 10 where I can install pywin32 without having any problem but When I'm going to install pywin32 on Cpanel(Namecheap) in my Django app then showing the following error. Please notice the image where everything is almost the same version just python 3.9.2 on windows and python 3.8.6 on Cpanel. Also, I tried several pywin32 version on CPanel but didn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCRsH.png)

Which procedure I should follow to install pywin32 or pypiwin32 on my Cpanel?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Cpanel is for Linux. py**win**32 is for Windows. You cannot install pywin32 on Linux, and frankly should not even have a reason to try it. What do you need pywin32 on Cpanel for?

Comment: Can I get around a pywin32 dependency in a python app in docker?

Comment: Here is the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66471912/how-can-i-get-around-a-pywin32-dependency-in-a-python-app-in-docker